# Replacing if statements and global variables in an Python Apache Beam pipeline

Tags: python, if-statement, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I am getting acquainted with the Python Apache Beam SDK. A feature that I keep on wanting to use is if statements. For example, I create a PCollection which then flows into another PCollection based on some result. I am aware that the the `Partition` function can be used to perform such splits.

Here is the catch though. With the `Partition` function, the downstream PCollections will always remain active or at least receive an empty PCollection from the parent. This becomes a problem when the desired outcome is: *write to a file if a condition is met, otherwise leave it alone*.

More specifically, my scenario is as follows: I call an API which either returns some data or a None. I want to overwrite some file only if the API returns new data else I want to leave it as is.

Here is my implementation that makes use of if statements and a globally defined variable. The pipeline runs using the `DirectRunner` (local machine implementation) but I think that this implementation is very bad practice. I do not think this approach will hold if I were to deploy it to Google Cloud DataFlow in a data-heavy environment.

Please help me to figure out a way of replacing such if statements and global variables that maintain some state for the if statement to make use of. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
import os

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'first_service_account_key.json'

N = 5

url = 'gs://test_bucket-321/routing_test'

text_file = url + '/test.txt'

pipeline_options = {
    'job_name':'test-if-statement',
    'project': 'tensile-proxy-386313' ,
    'runner': 'DirectRunner', 
}
pipeline_options = PipelineOptions.from_dictionary(pipeline_options) 
pipeline = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)


is_None = False

def api_sim():
    # Simulates the pull from an API
    global is_None  # Global: outside of the pipeline. Problem?
    if np.random.uniform(0,1) < 0.5:
        is_None = False
        for i in range(N):
            yield np.random.randint(0,100)
    else:
        is_None = True
        return None

def custom_print(element):
    print(element)
    return element

api_pull = (
    pipeline
    | 'simulate an api pull' >> beam.Create(api_sim())
    | beam.Map(custom_print)
    )

if not is_None:
    # Conditional write
    writer = api_pull | 'conditional write' >> beam.io.WriteToText(text_file)


pipeline.run()
```

#### EDIT:

Here is another solution. Although it still seems like I am not using best practices though returning a PCollection in a ParDo function.

```
def api_sim():
    # Simulates the pull from an API
    if np.random.uniform(0, 1) < 0.9:
        for i in range(N):
            yield np.random.randint(0, 100)


def custom_print(element):
    print(element)
    return element


class ConditionalWriteToText(beam.DoFn):
    
    def process(self,element):
        if element is not None:
            yield element | beam.io.WriteToText(text_file)


api = (
       pipeline
       | beam.Create(api_sim())
       | beam.Map(custom_print)
       | beam.combiners.ToList()
       | beam.ParDo(ConditionalWriteToText())
       )

pipeline.run()
```

Comment: Your solution ConditionalWriteToText looks fine, just use it.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the comment here, considering that you have only one conditional output, it seems to be fine to handle by sending downstream or not.

More generally, Beam supports multiple outputs, so if you want to decide which PCollection to feed, you can use multiple outputs / tags to route.

This should help if you are interested: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#additional-outputs

Answer (score 0):

First, never ever use global varibales in Beam (constants are fine though)! Beam as a framework provides you with out-of-the box parallelism, i.e. it takes care to initialize new workers correctly (be it in Dataflow or any other runner), deals with the communication between the parallel executed parts of your code and the workers etc. When you introduce a global variable I believe this is no longer the case. At the very least, you will have racing conditions when multiple workers are reading/writing from/to this global variable.

Your second approach is nearly correct, however, `DoFn`s are not the place to outsource pipeline snippets. It is code which is applied to all the elements of an input `PCollection` and yields an output `PCollection`, from the [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#pardo)

> A given DoFn instance generally **gets invoked one or more times** to
> **process** some **arbitrary bundle of elements**. However, Beam doesn’t
> guarantee an exact number of invocations; it may be invoked multiple
> times on a given worker node to account for failures and retries. As
> such, you can cache information across multiple calls to your
> processing method, but if you do so, make sure the implementation does
> not depend on the number of invocations.

It might be useful to take a look at the [execution model](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runtime/model/#processing-of-elements) to get a deeper understanding, in particular regarding bundles etc.

Rule of thumb: if you want to pipe `|` something it should not be within a `DoFn`, but in a `PTransform` (btw most build-in methods are PTranforms, such as [`beam.io.WriteToText`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.6.0/apache_beam.io.textio.html#apache_beam.io.textio.WriteToText)).

In your case it should look like this

```
class FilterRelevantElements(beam.DoFn):  # your original ConditionalWriteToText
    
    def process(self,element):
        if element is not None:
            yield element

class ConditionalWriteToText(beam.PTransform):
    def expand(self, pcoll):
        return (
            pcoll
            | beam.ParDo(FilterRelevantElements)
            | beam.io.WriteToText(text_file )
        )
```

and then

```
api = (
       pipeline
       | beam.Create(api_sim())
       | beam.Map(custom_print)
       | beam.combiners.ToList()
       | ConditionalWriteToText()  # note the missing ParDo since it is a PTransform
       )
```

While this works, it is prudent to simply make use of the existing [build-in Beam functions](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/overview/). In this case, you may get the same result by simply using [`beam.Filter`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/elementwise/filter/)

```
api = (
       pipeline
       | beam.Create(api_sim())
       | beam.Map(custom_print)
       | beam.combiners.ToList()
       | beam.Filter(lambda element: if element is not None)
       | beam.io.WriteToText(text_file )
       )
```

If the Function within `Filter` returns `false`, the code after is not executed.